# Инверсия в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как можно сделать инверсию в регулярном выражении, т.е. я хочу найти симметричную строку, например 12344321. Регулярное выражение для 12341234 будет примерно **`/(.*)\\1/`**. Как мне инвертировать **`\\1`**, если это вообще возможно?

Comment: имхо чисто средствами regexp не получится, и даже пытатся не стоит. проще будет поискать по маске на примере вашей строки `1(.*?)1` а потом каждое такое вхождение проверять на симметричность

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря — нельзя. Потому что невозможно построить конечный автомат без памяти, который принимает все палиндромы.

Но если конкретная реализация «регэкспов» круче, чем классические НКА то можно. Например, `/^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$/` в Perl (и именно в нем) может рекурсивно вызывать сам себя, за счет чего успешно работать. Но с PCRE в PHP такое не пройдет — в PCRE (но не Perl, несмотря на расшифровку первой буквы в PCRE!) совпадения «атомарны» и если группа однажды совпала с каким-то текстом, то больше она не будет обрабатываться, даже если в ней остались какие-либо альтернативы.

Впрочем, [нашелся вариант и для PHPшного PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746487/how-does-this-pcre-pattern-detect-palindromes):

```
$palindrome = '/(?x)
^
  (?:
      (.) (?=
              .*
              (
                \1
                (?(2) \2 | )
              )
              $
          )
  )*
  .?
  \2?
$
/';
```

Comment: Как приятно читать совершенно адекватные, а главное логически ответы! +1

Answer (score 1):

Как-то туманно вопрос звучит...

Если нужно переворачивать строку и искать в тексте совпадения, то так и делай. Простой цикл который складывает в новую переменную все символы исходной строки с конца к началу, а, потом, поиск в тексте совпадений с полученной строкой. В этом случае регэкспы вообще не нужны.

На счет перевернуть регэксп. Как ты себе это представляешь? Регулярные выражения - это специализированный язык для поиска и замены совпадений в тексте. В нем есть свои переменные, условия, циклы и даже рекурсивный спуск. Это тоже самое что пытаться перевернуть исходник на любом другом языке, например в PHP.

Это возможно только для частного случая, когда регулярка линейная. При любом другом варианте эта "инверсия" поведет себя неадекватно.